# How to find numerical difference between the number in two different <td>'s?

Tags: javascript

Here is my page: http://digidreamers.com/marketing/seo/microstrategy/

I have 18 columns (labeled: CHANGE) where I need to show the difference of the numerical values in the previous two columns ( < t d >'s CURRENT POSITION & LAST MONTH).

Currently, I enter the first two columns manually, then calculate the difference of the two in the last column to figure out the difference. (I'm a designer) I'd like to throw in a script to calculate the last column.

Comment: The page doesnt exist: 

"The requested URL /seo/marketing/microstrategy/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Where and how do you put orig values? Php or pure html?

Comment: Sorry guys, I was trying to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell looked like this

```
<td id='tdid'>400</td>
```

You could use javascript to get this value:

```
var value1 = document.getElementById ("tdid").innerText;
```

Now, if you got the two values and stored it into value1 and value2, you can use javascript to set the third cell like this:

```
document.getElementById ("tdid").innerText = parseInt(value1) - parseInt(value2);
```

Comment: Edit: Added parseInt. I was going for the key concept, and missed it out. Thanks @RASG

Answer (score 0):

you know jQuery can make your life easier, right? :)

here is an alternate solution:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id='tdid1' class='aaa'>400</td>
        <td id='tdid2' class='aaa'>300</td>
        <td id='resu'></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>

<button id='res'>result</button>
```

**JS**

```
var value1 = $("#tdid1").text();
var value2 = $("#tdid2").text();

var result = parseInt(value1) - parseInt(value2);

$('#res').click(function() { $('#resu').html(result) })
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/pqtmb/

*just a reminder: by using javascript, you are letting the client do the calculation, not your server. if for any reason the js fails, the user will not be able to see the column with the result.*